# React JS- Internacionalização de imagens

Tags: react, internacionalização

Boa tarde,
estou usando a biblioteca *React-intl* para fazer a internacionalização de textos em pt_br e inglês em um projeto de aplicação web React, porém necessito traduzir as imagens também e não faço ideia em como fazer isso.
Para a tradução dos textos estou usando *FormattedMessage*, mais ou menos assim:

```
<p><FormattedMessage id={"text"} defaultMessage={"Texto original"}/></p>
```

Tentei usar a mesma lógica para imagens mas não encontrei nada parecido. As imagens em pt_br e en são chamadas em tags `<img src={}/>` depois na aplicação. Como posso conseguir mudar a imagem dependendo da linguagem que o usuário estiver usando?

Comment: As imagens estão em algum endereço, ou estão locais no projeto?

Comment: Você necessita mudar a imagem de acordo com a linguagem?

Comment: Elas estão no local do projeto. Tenho a mesma imagem em pt-br e en e necessita mudar elas de acordo com a linguagem que o usuário está vendo o site (no caso, se não tiver especificado o default é pt-br)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `injectIntl`, para receber o valor de `intl` e verificar qual a linguagem a ser usada para fazer uma condição e assim renderizar a imagem que deseja.

Exemplo

```
import {injectIntl, intlShape} from 'react-intl';

const MeuComponente = ({intl}) => {
   return (
     <React.Fragment>
      { 
       intl.locale === "pt_br" ?
          <img src={require('../imagemPortugues.png')} />
        :
          <img src={require('../imagemIngles.png')} />
       }
     </React.Fragment>
    )

}
export default injectIntl(MeuComponente);
```

Comment: Fiz assim e funcionou, mt obrigado cara! Bem mais fácil do que imaginava!